# VBA I need a way to research multiple 1000*1000 Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

The Excel file is just full of worksheets full of numbers. One worksheet contains one number only one time.
I have some code that looks for a number through all the worksheets one by one with a For loop of 1000 * 1000.
It finds the names of the worksheets containing that number and displays it for someone to select the worksheet.
Once a worksheet is selected, the code writes "Yes" on the cell next to the number

What way of searching the number would be the fastest?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try using Excel "Find" feature with "Workbook" option...  You can even use that in VBA.

Comment: What have you tried?  What has been the problem?

Comment: Yes We use the excel Find feature but as we use it everyday it seems like we are loosing a lot of time. A VBA macro would be perfect.

Comment: I have a working code but while using a For loop of 1000*1000, it just takes too much time

Answer (score 0):

The code below will search through each worksheet in a workbook and search for the number `2` (Change to what you want) and then write `Yes` in the cell next to it

**Updated code after comments**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindNumber()
    Dim c As Range, firstAddress As Range
    Dim client As String
    Dim ticket As Integer
    Dim calc As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        calc = .calculation
        .calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    client = InputBox("Please enter client name and ticket number (e.g. Client, ticketnumber)")

    On Error GoTo Err

    ticket = Int(Split(client, ",")(1))
    client = Split(client, ",")(0)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(client).UsedRange
        Set c = .Find(what:=ticket)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            Set firstAddress = c
            Do
                c.Offset(0, 1) = "Yes"
                Set c = .FindNext(c)
            Loop Until Not c Is Nothing And c.Address = firstAddress.Address
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Exit Sub
Err:
    MsgBox "Couldn't find Client or ticket number"
    With Application
        .calculation = calc
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!

Comment: If this answers your question please click on the tick next to it to mark it as answered

Comment: Just a problem : from all the worksheets that will contain the number I look for, I want to be able to chose only one from a list of all the worksheets containing that number, so how could we modify this code for this to happen?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand. How will you be selecting the numbers?

Comment: We use it this way: we have at work (A climbing Gym) a Big excel file containing multiple worksheets, one worksheet = one client we sold hundreds or thousands of entrance tickets to. Those clients distribute the tickets to their staff and when people come with their tickets we have two information: the number of the ticket and the name of the client. This means we have to know what worksheets contains the ticket number, and then select the right worksheet from the list of worksheets that contain the ticket number

Comment: Try the update. This will match the Client to the sheet (Using the clients name) and then find the ticket number specified in the `InputBox`

Comment: Thanks again for this code, I will try to use this for sure. The problem is really that I cannot assign a client name from the beggining, I need to see the list of clients that contain the number and select it from it.      On my actual code it make a list of the names of all the worksheets containing that number and I choose the client from this list. My only problem is my search method. I will share my code and you'll see

Comment: To list the sheets store the `c.Parent` in collection or on a spare sheet and use the list to populate a combo-box.  You could also lose the `Not c Is Nothing` in the loop as you're not replacing the value (as is the case in the MS example for Find). The find will continue looping until `c.Address = firstAddress.Address`